# How to construct a dynamic where filter in EF.Core to handle equals, LIKE, gt, lt, etc

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic, .net-core

Please how do we construct a dynamic where filter in EF.Core to handle:

```
Query.Where(fieldName, compareMode, value)
```

I basically Expect to use it like below:

```
    [HttpGet(Name = nameof(GetStaff))]
    public IActionResult GetStaffAsync([FromQuery] QueryParams p)
    {
      var s = db.Staff.AsNoTracking()
   .Where(p.filter_field, p.filter_mode, p.filter_value)
   .OrderByMember(p.sortBy, p.descending);

      var l = new Pager<Staff>(s, p.page, p.rowsPerPage);

      return Ok(l);
    }

//Helpers
      public class QueryParams
      {
        public bool descending { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; } = 1;
        public int rowsPerPage { get; set; } = 5;

        public string sortBy { get; set; }

        public onject filter_value { get; set; }
        public string filter_field { get; set; }
        public string filter_mode { get; set; }
      }

  public class Pager<T>
  {
    public int pages { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }

    public Pager(IEnumerable<T> items, int offset, int limit)
    {
      Items = items.Skip((offset - 1) * limit).Take(limit).ToList<T>();
      total = items.Count();
      pages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)total / limit);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the formal signature of the method you are seeking for? Or at least the parameters - e.g. `propertyName` - `string`, `comparison` (`LIKE`, `=`, `>`, `<` etc) - `string` or some `enum`?, `value` - `object` or `string` etc. Basically what you have at the time you want to build the predicate.

Comment: @IvanStoev I get your point, i guess the flexibility of an enum is best, and an object for the search value is best (to permit different types). I have edited my question

Comment: There is a .NET Core version of the [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) library.

Comment: @IvanStoev i guess its an extension of what you did before, with a switch-case on the compare method

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming all you have is the entity type and strings representing the property, comparison operator and the value, building dynamic predicate can be done with something like this:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string comparison, string value)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var left = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.Property);
        var body = MakeComparison(left, comparison, value);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }

    private static Expression MakeComparison(Expression left, string comparison, string value)
    {
        switch (comparison)
        {
            case "==":
                return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, left, value);
            case "!=":
                return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.NotEqual, left, value);
            case ">":
                return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThan, left, value);
            case ">=":
                return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual, left, value);
            case "<":
                return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThan, left, value);
            case "<=":
                return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual, left, value);
            case "Contains":
            case "StartsWith":
            case "EndsWith":
                return Expression.Call(MakeString(left), comparison, Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string)));
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Invalid comparison operator '{comparison}'.");
        }
    }

    private static Expression MakeString(Expression source)
    {
        return source.Type == typeof(string) ? source : Expression.Call(source, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
    }

    private static Expression MakeBinary(ExpressionType type, Expression left, string value)
    {
        object typedValue = value;
        if (left.Type != typeof(string))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                typedValue = null;
                if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(left.Type) == null)
                    left = Expression.Convert(left, typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(left.Type));
            }
            else
            {
                var valueType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(left.Type) ?? left.Type;
                typedValue = valueType.IsEnum ? Enum.Parse(valueType, value) :
                    valueType == typeof(Guid) ? Guid.Parse(value) :
                    Convert.ChangeType(value, valueType);
            }
        }
        var right = Expression.Constant(typedValue, left.Type);
        return Expression.MakeBinary(type, left, right);
    }
}
```

Basically building property accessor (with nested property support), parsing the comparison operator and calling the corresponding operator/method, dealing with from/to `string` and from/to nullable type conversions. It can be extended to handle EF Core specific functions like `EF.Functions.Like` by adding the corresponding branch.

It can be used directly (in case you need to combine it with other predicates) or via custom extension method like this:

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string comparison, string value)
    {
        return source.Where(ExpressionUtils.BuildPredicate<T>(propertyName, comparison, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I'd like to be able to do an OR with two or more string-parameter-Wheres. I have not see an example. But maybe using PredicateBuilder would be a piece of that puzzle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621450/dynamic-where-clause-or-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: In `MakeBinary` this `Convert.ChangeType(value, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(left.Type) ?? left.Type);` errors on Guids, so I had to add an `if else` condition for them.

Comment: @jaycer Good catch! I forgot that `Convert` doesn't handle `Guid`s. Answer updated accorrdingly.

Comment: great answer! But how can i extend this to work with enums?

Comment: @marvstar The `value` argument type could be changed from `string` to `object` and then the conversion logic must be modified to adjust the `value` based on `left.Type`. Currently it's the opposite.

Comment: I achived it with the following line `valueType.IsEnum ? valueType.IsEnum ? Enum.ToObject(valueType, Convert.ToInt32(value))`.
just added this to the ternary assignment in the MakeBinary function.

Should i add this to your answer?

Comment: @marvstar Thanks for your comments. Disregard my previous response. I've corrected the answer similar to what you suggested, but with `Enum.Parse` which handles passing enum values as both text or int.

Comment: @IvanStoev Spaciba !! I was searching for this for ages now! ✔

Comment: Topic is a old but I have a question. How can I handle datetime in this function? I'm trying to filter by date only in the datetime field.

Comment: @GökhanYILDIZ Simply use `Date` property of the `DateTime` field inside the `propertyPath` string , e.g. `query.Where("YourPropertyName.Date", ...)`

Comment: @IvanStoev Could you please elaborate more about Datetime matching or time range matching by any chance? And plus any advice for filtering by in [a,b,c]? Highly appreciated.

Comment: @Rich Sure. But comments are quite limited, why don't you post your own question, you can refer to this one and provide your specific use cases.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi Ivan, I have created another page for extended user cases. Please have a look. Thanks in advance.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76917734/how-to-construct-a-dynamic-where-filters-in-ef-core-to-handle-datetime-range-ar

Answer (score 9):

based on Ivans answer this is what i came up with

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string comparison, object value)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var left = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
        var body = MakeComparison(left, comparison, value);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }

    static Expression MakeComparison(Expression left, string comparison, object value)
    {
        var constant = Expression.Constant(value, left.Type);
        switch (comparison)
        {
            case "==":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, left, constant);
            case "!=":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.NotEqual, left, constant);
            case ">":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThan, left, constant);
            case ">=":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual, left, constant);
            case "<":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThan, left, constant);
            case "<=":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual, left, constant);
            case "Contains":
            case "StartsWith":
            case "EndsWith":
                if (value is string)
                {
                    return Expression.Call(left, comparison, Type.EmptyTypes, constant);
                }
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Comparison operator '{comparison}' only supported on string.");
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Invalid comparison operator '{comparison}'.");
        }
    }
}
```

and some tests

```
public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Nested()
    {
        var list = new List<Target>
        {
            new Target
            {
                Member = "a"
            },
            new Target
            {
                Member = "bb"
            }
        };

        var result = list.AsQueryable()
            .Where(ExpressionUtils.BuildPredicate<Target>("Member.Length", "==", 2))
            .Single();
        Assert.Equal("bb", result.Member);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Field()
    {
        var list = new List<TargetWithField>
        {
            new TargetWithField
            {
                Field = "Target1"
            },
            new TargetWithField
            {
                Field = "Target2"
            }
        };

        var result = list.AsQueryable()
            .Where(ExpressionUtils.BuildPredicate<TargetWithField>("Field", "==", "Target2"))
            .Single();
        Assert.Equal("Target2", result.Field);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("Name", "==", "Person 1", "Person 1")]
    [InlineData("Name", "!=", "Person 2", "Person 1")]
    [InlineData("Name", "Contains", "son 2", "Person 2")]
    [InlineData("Name", "StartsWith", "Person 2", "Person 2")]
    [InlineData("Name", "EndsWith", "son 2", "Person 2")]
    [InlineData("Age", "==", 13, "Person 2")]
    [InlineData("Age", ">", 12, "Person 2")]
    [InlineData("Age", "!=", 12, "Person 2")]
    [InlineData("Age", ">=", 13, "Person 2")]
    [InlineData("Age", "<", 13, "Person 1")]
    [InlineData("Age", "<=", 12, "Person 1")]
    public void Combos(string name, string expression, object value, string expectedName)
    {
        var people = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person
            {
                Name = "Person 1",
                Age = 12
            },
            new Person
            {
                Name = "Person 2",
                Age = 13
            }
        };

        var result = people.AsQueryable()
            .Where(ExpressionUtils.BuildPredicate<Person>(name, expression, value))
            .Single();
        Assert.Equal(expectedName, result.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the answer I found here: [Linq WHERE EF.Functions.Like - Why direct properties work and reflection does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320767/linq-where-ef-functions-like-why-direct-properties-work-and-reflection-does-no)

I chucked together a version for those using NpgSQL as their EF Core provider as you will need to use the `ILike` function instead if you want case-insensitivity, also added a second version which combines a bunch of properties into a single `Where()` clause:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string searchTerm)
    {
        // Check property name
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));
        }

        // Check the search term
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searchTerm));
        }

        // Check the property exists
        var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The property {typeof(T)}.{propertyName} was not found.", nameof(propertyName));
        }

        // Check the property type
        if(property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The specified property must be of type {typeof(string)}.", nameof(propertyName));
        }

        // Get expression constants
        var searchPattern = "%" + searchTerm + "%";
        var itemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        var functions = Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF).GetProperty(nameof(EF.Functions)));
        var likeFunction = typeof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions.ILike), new Type[] { functions.Type, typeof(string), typeof(string) });

        // Build the property expression and return it
        Expression selectorExpression = Expression.Property(itemParameter, property.Name);
        selectorExpression = Expression.Call(null, likeFunction, functions, selectorExpression, Expression.Constant(searchPattern));
        return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(selectorExpression, itemParameter));
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames, string searchTerm)
    {
        // Check property name
        if (!(propertyNames?.Any() ?? false))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyNames));
        }

        // Check the search term
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searchTerm));
        }

        // Check the property exists
        var properties = propertyNames.Select(p => typeof(T).GetProperty(p)).AsEnumerable();
        if (properties.Any(p => p == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"One or more specified properties was not found on type {typeof(T)}: {string.Join(",", properties.Where(p => p == null).Select((p, i) => propertyNames.ElementAt(i)))}.", nameof(propertyNames));
        }

        // Check the property type
        if (properties.Any(p => p.PropertyType != typeof(string)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The specified properties must be of type {typeof(string)}: {string.Join(",", properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType != typeof(string)).Select(p => p.Name))}.", nameof(propertyNames));
        }

        // Get the expression constants
        var searchPattern = "%" + searchTerm + "%";
        var itemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        var functions = Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF).GetProperty(nameof(EF.Functions)));
        var likeFunction = typeof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions.ILike), new Type[] { functions.Type, typeof(string), typeof(string) });

        // Build the expression and return it
        Expression selectorExpression = null;
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var previousSelectorExpression = selectorExpression;
            selectorExpression = Expression.Property(itemParameter, property.Name);
            selectorExpression = Expression.Call(null, likeFunction, functions, selectorExpression, Expression.Constant(searchPattern));
            if(previousSelectorExpression != null)
            {
                selectorExpression = Expression.Or(previousSelectorExpression, selectorExpression);
            }
        }
        return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(selectorExpression, itemParameter));
    }
```