# Linq WHERE EF.Functions.Like - Why direct properties work and reflection does not?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to perform a simple LIKE action on the database site, while having query building services based on generic types. I found out while debugging however, that performing `EF.Functions.Like()` with reflection does not work as expected:

`The LINQ expression 'where __Functions_0.Like([c].GetType().GetProperty("FirstName").GetValue([c], null).ToString(), "%Test%")' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.`.

---

**The code that makes the difference**

*That works*:

```cs
var query = _context.Set<Customer>().Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.FirstName, "%Test%"));
```

*This throws the warning & tries to resolve in memory*:

```cs
var query = _context.Set<Customer>().Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.GetType().GetProperty("FirstName").GetValue(c, null).ToString(), "%Test%"));
```

**Does the Linq query builder or the EF.Functions not support reflections?**

Sorry if the questions seem basic, it's my first attempt with .NET Core :)

Comment: It is possible, but you shouldn't do it. Entity Framework can't evaluate an expression containing reflection to SQL. So it will attempt load everything into memory and then executing the expression. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can provide an alternative

Comment: Gave a more detailed answer in a comment for @Serdar. Basically - a generic query params search functionality by extending an IQueryable, where the `queryParam.Key` a model class property is, and `queryParam.Value` the pattern used in *LIKE* clause.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In EF the *lambdas* are *ExpressionTrees* and the expressions are translated to T-SQL so that the *query* can be executed in the database.

You can create an extension method like so:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string searchTerm)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
    {
        return source;
    }

    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

    if (property is null)
    {
        return source;
    }

    searchTerm = "%" + searchTerm + "%";
    var itemParameter = Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

    var functions = Property(null, typeof(EF).GetProperty(nameof(EF.Functions)));
    var like = typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), new Type[] { functions.Type, typeof(string), typeof(string) });

    Expression expressionProperty = Property(itemParameter, property.Name);

    if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
    {
        expressionProperty = Call(expressionProperty, typeof(object).GetMethod(nameof(object.ToString), new Type[0]));
    }

    var selector = Call(
               null,
               like,
               functions,
               expressionProperty,
               Constant(searchTerm));

    return source.Where(Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(selector, itemParameter));
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var query = _context.Set<Customer>().Search("FirstName", "Test").ToList();
var query2 = _context.Set<Customer>().Search("Age", "2").ToList();
```

For reference this was the `Customer` I used:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was something I was wishing for - had already an extension method for pagination. Have yet to read up on expression trees to fully understand your code. Are you using some classes from an extension package? `Parameter`, `Property`, `Call`, `Constant` and `Lambda` give me some issues.

Comment: I am just using a static using, like so: `using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;`

Comment: Can't use for EFCore, show could not be translated, could you please help?

Comment: Can't use for EFCore, show "could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'object.ToString' failed", could you please help?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer, no.

EntityFramework is trying to covert your where clause in to a SQL Query. There is no native support for reflection in this conversation.

You have 2 options here. You can construct your text outside of your query or directly use property itself. Is there any specific reason for not using something like following?

```
var query = _context.Set<Customer>().Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.FirstName, "%Test%"));
```

Comment: I try to make a search feature class for provided query params (dict - k: Properties, v: searchString) that is injected where there search feature is required. Eventually, I have a function `public IQueryable<T> ApplySearch<T>(IQueryable<T> efQuery) where T : class` that, while looping through the query params, extends the query with additional where clauses: `efQuery = efQuery.Where(t => EF.Functions.Like(t.GetType().GetProperty(queryParam.Key).GetValue(t).ToString(), "%" + queryParam.Value + "%"));`. That was the main goal.

Comment: Using reflaction is almost opposite of EntityFramework. Normally you need to use ORM Tools when you have strong types queries. In your case, you are trying to build something dynamically. You can still build it with EntityFramework, but it may requires some nasty code. Instead of that, you can consider executing constructed queries by your reflection logic with EF maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that every ExpresionTree that you put in Where clause has to be translated into SQL query.

Because of that, ExpressionTrees that you can write are quite limited, you have to stick to some rules, thats why reflection is not supported.

Image that instead of :

```
var query = _context.Set<Customer>().Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.GetType().GetProperty("FirstName").GetValue(c, null).ToString(), "%Test%"));
```

You write something like:

```
var query = _context.Set<Customer>().Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(SomeMethodThatReturnsString(c), "%Test%"));
```

It would mean that EF is able to translate any c# code to SQL query - it's obviously not true :)

Comment: Awesome comment, thank you! Did not think that through. Have to follow up what is actually translatable. Pozdrawiam! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I chucked together a version of the accepted answer for those using NpgSQL as their EF Core provider as you will need to use the `ILike` function instead if you want case-insensitivity, also added a second version which combines a bunch of properties into a single `Where()` clause:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string searchTerm)
    {
        // Check property name
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));
        }

        // Check the search term
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searchTerm));
        }

        // Check the property exists
        var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The property {typeof(T)}.{propertyName} was not found.", nameof(propertyName));
        }

        // Check the property type
        if(property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The specified property must be of type {typeof(string)}.", nameof(propertyName));
        }

        // Get expression constants
        var searchPattern = "%" + searchTerm + "%";
        var itemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        var functions = Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF).GetProperty(nameof(EF.Functions)));
        var likeFunction = typeof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions.ILike), new Type[] { functions.Type, typeof(string), typeof(string) });

        // Build the property expression and return it
        Expression selectorExpression = Expression.Property(itemParameter, property.Name);
        selectorExpression = Expression.Call(null, likeFunction, functions, selectorExpression, Expression.Constant(searchPattern));
        return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(selectorExpression, itemParameter));
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames, string searchTerm)
    {
        // Check property name
        if (!(propertyNames?.Any() ?? false))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyNames));
        }

        // Check the search term
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searchTerm));
        }

        // Check the property exists
        var properties = propertyNames.Select(p => typeof(T).GetProperty(p)).AsEnumerable();
        if (properties.Any(p => p == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"One or more specified properties was not found on type {typeof(T)}: {string.Join(",", properties.Where(p => p == null).Select((p, i) => propertyNames.ElementAt(i)))}.", nameof(propertyNames));
        }

        // Check the property type
        if (properties.Any(p => p.PropertyType != typeof(string)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The specified properties must be of type {typeof(string)}: {string.Join(",", properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType != typeof(string)).Select(p => p.Name))}.", nameof(propertyNames));
        }

        // Get the expression constants
        var searchPattern = "%" + searchTerm + "%";
        var itemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        var functions = Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF).GetProperty(nameof(EF.Functions)));
        var likeFunction = typeof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions.ILike), new Type[] { functions.Type, typeof(string), typeof(string) });

        // Build the expression and return it
        Expression selectorExpression = null;
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var previousSelectorExpression = selectorExpression;
            selectorExpression = Expression.Property(itemParameter, property.Name);
            selectorExpression = Expression.Call(null, likeFunction, functions, selectorExpression, Expression.Constant(searchPattern));
            if(previousSelectorExpression != null)
            {
                selectorExpression = Expression.Or(previousSelectorExpression, selectorExpression);
            }
        }
        return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(selectorExpression, itemParameter));
    }
```