# IQueryable WHERE inside a for loop does not produce expected result

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**Objective:**

Implementing AND filter. Where users input list of keywords in an input, then the list gets filtered based on the first word, then the next and so on. For instance, when they input "May", their list should be filtered to show only records for the month of may. In case, they input "May June", they should get empty list. Because, you shouldn't find records for the month of June within a list for the month of May

**My failed attempt:**

Below example does not work as I expected to

```
List<string> keywords; // e.g. "May", "June"

for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Length; i++) {                
    string searchTerm = keywords[i];
    entityObj = entityObj.Where(x =>
            x.Month.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
            x.Year.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
            x.Product.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm));
}
```

`entityObj` is of type `IQueryable<SomeEntity>`. Assume there is a table in the database with **Month, Year and Product** columns. On the first iteration, `searchTerm` will have *May* as its value. So, entityObj should return `IQueryable` object for records that only has *May* in the **Month** column. I expect the second iteration to return nothing, since we are looking for value of *June* in a result of the previous iteration which has only *May* result. However, I am getting records that have *June* value instead. No matter how many keywords I have, it is always returning the result based on the last element in the list which is the last iteration.

When I do below

```
string searchTerm = "May";
entityObj = entityObj.Where(x =>
            x.Month.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
            x.Year.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
            x.Product.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm));

searchTerm = "June";
entityObj = entityObj.Where(x =>
            x.Month.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
            x.Year.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
            x.Product.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm));
```

I get the result that I expect, empty list. However, When I do that inside a for loop, it does not work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you show us where you declare entityObj in your sample?

Comment: @MichaelSander it is outside the for loop

Comment: It would be easier to answer, if you provide compilable code to reproduce. I tried to reproduce the issue but my code is running as expected.

Comment: can you check and post the the formed SQL query?

Comment: Could you try this : create a filter method and put your for loop in it (with entityObj & keywords as param). Inside your method, create a temp variable (IQueryable<SomeEntity>) and assign entityObj to it. Then work with the temp variable instead of the entityObj directly.

Comment: can you show where you actually iterate / enumerate / consume the query? you say about the "second iteration" - your iteration never actually consumes the query, so it is hard to be 100% clear about what we're seeing; also - product names might conceivably be to blame; "Mayflower" etc

Comment: what's really odd is your "When I do below ... I get the result that I expect, empty list." - because that query **does not** represent the presumably zero intersection of May and June; it is actually "June", applied twice (due to how "captured variables" work) - so if you have data in June, you should see it. Hence the details of how you're consuming this might *really, really matter*

Comment: I think what you really want/need is an adaptation of this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58326867/3501212

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be because of using same variable entityObj.

First of all, `entityObj` is an IQueryable - right? That means it just a query and not a collection or list.

Secondly do not use same variable to store the result as well.

Instead try this it should work fine

```
string searchTerm = "May";
var mainList= entityObj.Where(x => x.Month.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                   x.Year.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                   x.Product.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm)).ToList();

searchTerm = "June";

var subList = mainList.Where(x => x.Month.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                  x.Year.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                   x.Product.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm));
```

I am sure this should work but even this one doesn't work then you might want to look into how C# is referencing variable assigning memory allocation.

Don't go too deep but there is shallow copy and deep copy techniques you might want to look into.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-c-sharp/