# How to find string in any table column Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to query a table for records where any column contains a string?

The following would do this for a single Column, but is there a way to do this without explicitly listing every single column with or `||` operators?

```
var result = await _context.Table
                           .Where(tbl => tbl.Column.Contains("value")) 
                           .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: No, there's not. Even with raw SQL, you still have to specify the column names or things become [even more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52715388/8967612).

Comment: It is possible but needs ExpressionTree building. Any criteria on which columns? All string properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make all fields search in ASP.Net Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424866/how-to-make-all-fields-search-in-asp-net-api)