# How to construct a dynamic where filters in EF.Core to handle Datetime range, Array and Pagination etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to build customized filtering which is similar to the requirements in this link.
[How to construct a dynamic where filter in EF.Core to handle equals, LIKE, gt, lt, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306955/how-to-construct-a-dynamic-where-filter-in-ef-core-to-handle-equals-like-gt-l)

But I would like to also supplement Datetime Range, exists in Array, and also pagination like below

```
filter="DatetimeProperty:{03082023111213, 04062023111312}&GroupIdProperty:[1,2,3]&PageNumber:3&PageSize:10"
```

Any ideas or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to read your filter string,would you accept write it in json?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng narh... the requirement is a string in filter