# Ordering By Child Entity EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have an extension method to sort my entities, and in some cases i need to sort on a property of a child collection

```
 public static IQueryable<Payment> SetSort(this IQueryable<Payment> payments, string sortProperty, string direction)


            if (string.Equals(sortProperty, PaymentSortProperties.TimeStamp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return sortDirection == SortDirection.Asc ? payments.OrderBy(x => x.History.OrderBy(h=> h.Timestamp)) : payments.OrderByDescending(x => x.History.OrderByDescending(h => h.Timestamp));
            }

}
```

Called from

```
 public async Task<IPagedList<Payment>> Get(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string sortProperty, string direction, string searchString)
    {
            var result = _data.Payments
                .Include(x => x.History)
                .ThenInclude(x=>x.Status)
                .Filter(searchString)
            .SetSort(sortProperty, direction);

            return await result.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize);         
    }
```

i get the error `System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.`

I've seen examples that suggest i do it like this

```
    if (string.Equals(sortProperty, PaymentSortProperties.TimeStamp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return sortDirection == SortDirection.Asc ?
 payments.OrderBy(x => x.History.Min(h=> h.Timestamp)) 
: payments.OrderByDescending(x => x.History.Max(h => h.Timestamp));
                }
```

but that triggers a `SELECT n + 1` query (ie causing all entities in dB to be loaded into memory, and then sorted).

What is the right way of going about it?

Comment: There are better ways to add a sort expression dynamically, Just one of many examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36303246/861716. But that doesn't solve your direct problem, which is (probably) that you're trying to enter a dotted name. You don't show which property you try to sort by, so we have to guess.

Comment: The property i'm trying to sort by is Timestamp on the History collection, which is in the first code block.

Comment: Ah yes. How would image that ordering by the result of `x => x.History.OrderBy(h=> h.Timestamp)` should look like?

Comment: That the Payments are ordered by the earliest timestamp in the History collection (when using OrderBy)

Comment: You're trying to order collections is what I mean. Look closely at what your code does.

Comment: The example you've been shown is closer to the solution, what is the problem when using this code ? What problem does a `SELECT n+1` query causes ?

Comment: Select N+ 1 causes all entities in dB to be loaded into memory, and then sorted.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you, so what is the correct way to  order Payments  by the earliest timestamp in the History collection?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the `Min` / `Max` is the correct way in general. Unfortunately as you have noticed, EF Core (as of v2.0) still doesn't translate well (`GroupBy`) aggregate methods and falls back to client evaluation for processing them.

As a workaround, I could suggest the alternative pattern `OrderBy[Descending]` + `Select` + `FirstOrDefault` which luckily translates to SQL:

```
return sortDirection == SortDirection.Asc ?
    payments.OrderBy(p => p.History.OrderBy(h => h.Timestamp).Select(h => h.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()) :
    payments.OrderByDescending(x => x.History.OrderByDescending(h => h.Timestamp).Select(h => h.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault());
```

Here is the same encapsulated in a custom extension method:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TOuter> OrderBy<TOuter, TInner, TKey>(
        this IQueryable<TOuter> source,
        Expression<Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>>> innerCollectionSelector,
        Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> keySelector,
        bool ascending)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(innerCollectionSelector, keySelector, ascending, false);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TOuter> ThenBy<TOuter, TInner, TKey>(
        this IOrderedQueryable<TOuter> source,
        Expression<Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>>> innerCollectionSelector,
        Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> keySelector,
        bool ascending)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(innerCollectionSelector, keySelector, ascending, true);
    }

    static IOrderedQueryable<TOuter> OrderBy<TOuter, TInner, TKey>(
        this IQueryable<TOuter> source,
        Expression<Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>>> innerCollectionSelector,
        Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
        bool ascending, bool concat)
    {
        var parameter = innerCollectionSelector.Parameters[0];
        var innerOrderByMethod = ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        var innerOrderByCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), innerOrderByMethod, new[] { typeof(TInner), typeof(TKey) },
            innerCollectionSelector.Body, innerKeySelector);
        var innerSelectCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new[] { typeof(TInner), typeof(TKey) },
            innerOrderByCall, innerKeySelector);
        var innerFirstOrDefaultCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), "FirstOrDefault", new[] { typeof(TKey) },
            innerSelectCall);
        var outerKeySelector = Expression.Lambda(innerFirstOrDefaultCall, parameter);
        var outerOrderByMethod = concat ? ascending ? "ThenBy" : "ThenByDescending" : innerOrderByMethod;
        var outerOrderByCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), outerOrderByMethod, new[] { typeof(TOuter), typeof(TKey) },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(outerKeySelector));
        return (IOrderedQueryable<TOuter>)source.Provider.CreateQuery(outerOrderByCall);
    }
}
```

so you can use simply:

```
return payments.OrderBy(p => p.History, h => h.Timestamp, sortDirection == SortDirection.Asc)
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give that a try tomorrow