# how to use order by (both ASC and DESC) using Entity-Framework .Net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm using angular datatable to show a list of data and performing server side sorting. when I sort any column I receive the name of column and the sort order. I am using the below code to sort the record.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortField) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder))
            {
                if (sortOrder == "asc")
                {
                    if (sortField == "cnic")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.Cnic);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "firstName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "fatherName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.FatherName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "gender")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.Gender);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "designation")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.Designation);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "cadreName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.CadreName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "departmentName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.DepartmentName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "districtName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.DistrictName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "placeOfPostinfName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.PlaceOfPostingName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "bps")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.Bps);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "seniorityNo")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderBy(a => a.SeniorityNo);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (sortField == "cnic")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.Cnic);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "firstName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.FirstName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "fatherName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.FatherName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "gender")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.Gender);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "designation")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.Designation);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "cadreName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.CadreName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "departmentName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.DepartmentName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "districtName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.DistrictName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "placeOfPostinfName")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.PlaceOfPostingName);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "bps")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.Bps);
                    }
                    else if (sortField == "seniorityNo")
                    {
                        data2 = data2.OrderByDescending(a => a.SeniorityNo);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there any simple way to do this task... my expected code is, I want to only input the order column name (cnic, firstname, fathername...) and sort order (asc,desc). I have many columns and data table to sort and i need a universal method to to this.

Comment: If your data is not changing it doesn't make any sense to make the server calls just for sorting the data that is something you should handle on the client side.

Comment: @MihirDave I have millions of data and I'm using server side pagination i can not pop millions of records at once that,s why i am using server side...

Comment: Okay makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically order by certain entity properties in Entity Framework 7 (Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298868/how-to-dynamically-order-by-certain-entity-properties-in-entity-framework-7-cor)